# Свой Adapter для ListView

Tags: getview, android-sdk, android, java

Собственно из примеров, найденных в интернете, решил попробовать сделать свой собственный `Adapter` для `ListView`. Поэтому мой класс наследует `SimpleAdapter`.
Хотелось бы спросить вот о чем.

В конструктор передаются два параметра `String[] from`, `int[] to`

```
SimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, 
              String[] from, int[] to)
```

Хотелось бы знать для чего они (если можно, конкретный пример) и как к ним получить доступ, не создавая дополнительных переменных внутри своего класса?

**UPD:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
            int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
         super(context, data, resource, from, to); //вот передача параметров родителю
         //можно здесь скопировать from-to (но...)
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         //а теперь тут, ну очень хочется, получить доступ к from-to
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Адаптеры в Андроиде реализуют принцип связывания данных (наподобие WPF Data Binding).

Переменные в классе создавать необязательно:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    this, 
    list(), 
    android.R.layout.list, 
    new String[] {"title", "body"}, 
    new int[] {android.R.id.title, android.R.id.body}
);
```

Отображение происходит так:

- берется разметка с идентификатором `resource`,
- берется список отображаемых данных `data`,
- для каждого элемента списка с хэшем из `from` происходит отображение в элемент разметки с идентификатором из `to`.

Comment: За вторую часть спасибо, про from-to.
А первая, уважаемый, я же не об этом спрашивал. К счастью, я знаю как работают адаптеры в Java и для чего они.
Меня интересует наследование адаптера и доступ к to-from уже из класса наследника. см. UPD в вопросе