# Лист и привязка данных

Tags: android

Не помню, как даже сие чудо называется в андроиде, с ним вообще не работал. В общем, это список, где каждый элемент - это заголовок и его значение. Требуется реализовать такой список, а также нужно листнер, который будет будет обрабатывать клик элемента, чтобы показать меню с вариантами эдит и ремов. Также нужно иметь возможность читать данные списка из других классов, допустим список состоит из 10 элементов, для примера это телефонная книга, имя и телефон, так вот из другого класса нужно будет иметь возможность получить, допустим, список всех телефонов и работать с ними.

Comment: А что мешает нарисовать такой список в лэйаутах, а точнее строку этого списка, а потом использовать ListView + (заготовка для строки) + SimpleAdapter?
А можно еще SimpleAdapter немного модифицировать, но лично я пока не столкнулся с тем, чтобы это было необходимо.

Comment: Дак я с ними вообще не работал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите в моем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/7634/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-adapter-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-listview), пробуйте, удачи

Comment: Ну там еше нужно и клик на элементе обрабатывать

Comment: Так и обрабатывайте, это обычный ивент onListItemClick - implements OnItemClickListener